# Calculating shortest path with barriers using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, closest-facility, barriers

I have two layers of points (bus stops and facilities) within a city. I need to calculate which facility belongs to the closest bus stop. It can be done by near feature in ArcGIS Pro, but it doesn't count with physical barriers (buildings polygon etc).

How can I calculate it with barriers?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you could use Network Analyst.  An entry point to the Online Help for that is [Closest facility analysis layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/closest-facility-analysis-layer.htm#).

> The closest facility solver measures the cost of traveling between
> incidents and facilities and determines which are nearest to one
> other. When finding closest facilities, you can specify how many to
> find and whether the direction of travel is toward or away from them.
> The closest facility solver displays the best routes between incidents
> and facilities, reports their travel costs, and returns driving
> directions.

Further down on the same help page you will see that you can:

> **Import Barriers**
>
> Click Import Point Barriers, Import Line
> Barriers, or Import Polygon Barriers to load features from another data source, such as another
> feature layer, into one of the barriers feature classes (point
> barriers, line barriers, or polygon barriers).